# Node.js express and EJS passing object to template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm passing object to my template and want to display object details in html.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var user = req.session.passport.user;

    if ( user != 'undefined' ){
        res.render('pages/chat.ejs', {
            user_data: user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    } else {
        res.render('pages/chat.ejs', {
            user_data: false
        });
    }
});
```

and in my pages/chat.ejs:

```
<% if (!user_data) { %>
            <div class="buttons pull-right clearfix">
                <span data-action="chatLogin" class="pull-right bordered button_blue button">Log in</span>
            </div>
            <% } else { %>
            <div class="buttons pull-right clearfix">
                <span data-action="addChatMessage" class="pull-right bordered button_red button">SEND</span>
                <span class="pull-right bordered button_blue button" id="user_name_details">
                    <% user_data.user_display_name %>
                </span>
            </div>
            <% } %>
```

but there is nothing in `<% user_data.user_display_name %>` so how to display object details in template?

Comment: Are you sure `var user = req.session.passport.user;` contains `user_display_name` property? Can you console.log it?

Comment: `{ id: 70,
  social_id: '10073386359655**',
  social_type: 'facebook',
  direct_type: 0,
  direct_username: '0',
  direct_password: '0',
  user_display_name: 'Name Lastname',
  user_name_details: '[object Object]',
  user_photos: '',
  registered_ts: 2147483647,
  last_login_ts: 2147483647,
  user_ip: 'local',
  banned_info: 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

Use <%**=** user_data.user_display_name %>

<% %> is used for marking control flow.. It does not output any data

<%= %> is used to output the data of the enclosed variable in the template

<%- %> is used to output the unescaped value of the variable in the template so that characters like < and > don't get eaten by the HTML parser.